# Config Wizard Shows Missing Patches

Tags: 2010, configuration-wizard, patching

My farm started flashing errors in the 'Products and Patch Status' step in the Configuration Wizard and prevents the Wizard form moving ahead.  However, I know that the patches are installed and attempting to reinstall them fails as it's installer says there are not any products affected by the patch.  However, I can bypass the wizard successfully using the following command line.

```
psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd -installcheck -noinstallcheck
```

Running this performs smoothly with no errors however I still see the same errors when running the Wizard later. Seems like something is out of wack and I would like to identify it and clear it up.  The sites runs fine nonetheless.

If I run the psconfig command with the installcheck this is the following message as it relates to the missing components.

```
The following is missing on TXRDCVSPTCRW01T:
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 Core
Microsoft SharePoint Portal
Microsoft User Profiles
Microsoft SharePoint Portal English Language Pack
Microsoft Shared Components
Microsoft Shared Coms English Language Pack
Microsoft Slide Library
Microsoft InfoPath Forms Services
Microsoft InfoPath Form Services English Language Pack
Microsoft Word Server English Language Pack
PerformancePoint Services for SharePoint
PerformancePoint Services in SharePoint 1033 Language P
Microsoft Visio Services English Language Pack
Microsoft Visio Services Web Front End Components
Microsoft Excel Services Components
Microsoft Document Lifecycle Components
Microsoft Excel Services English Language Pack
Microsoft Search Server 2010 Core
Microsoft Search Server 2010 English Language Pack
Microsoft Document Lifecycle Components English Languag
Microsoft Slide Library English Language Pack
Microsoft Access Services Server
Microsoft Access Services English Language Pack
Microsoft Web Analytics Web Front End Components
Microsoft Web Analytics English Language Pack

Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP
Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 (KB2536

Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2536599)
Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)

Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2536599)

Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2536599)
Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)

Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2536599)
Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)

Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)

Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2536599)

Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2536599)

Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2536599)

Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2536599)

Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2536599)

Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2536599)
Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)

Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)

Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2536599)

Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2536599)

Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2536599)

Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2536599)


Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2536599)

Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2536599)

Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)

Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2536599)

Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2536599)

Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2536599)
Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)

Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)
```

Update:
As a followup. My environment did revert back to showing those errors in the wizard so I decided to remove the server from the farm and uninstall/reinstall SharePoint. However the installers would not run saying ther wer corrupt leaving me with the only option left of reimaging my machines and starting over. What a pain.

Comment: Thanks for this.
Altough I did install the SP2010 foundation SP1 (then run the config wizard) followed by the SO2010 Server SP1, I could not run the Config Wizard on my two other servers because it was complaining about missing patches. So the Foundation and Server SP2010 SP1 packages were installed, so I've installed the June CU on all serves and ran the command mentionned above (psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd -installcheck -noinstallcheck) which worked like a charm. I was then able to start the Config Waizard which did not complain anymore. 8-)

Answer (score 1):

As a followup. My environment did revert back to showing those errors in the wizard so I decided to remove the server from the farm and uninstall/reinstall SharePoint.  However the installers would not run saying ther wer corrupt leaving me with the only option left of reimaging my machines and starting over.  What a pain.

Answer (score 1):

the following trick worked great on our farm,

http://www.sharepointks.com/post/Cumulative-update-issue-The-upgrade-command-is-invalid-or-a-failure-has-been-encountered.aspx

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

The Get-SPProduct –local didn't do the trick for me however. But for me the problem is a bit more simple or complicated. I am trying to add a server to a farm (2-tier farm 1 wfe, 1 db). The server is an SQL Reporting Server, where, for integrated services I installed SharePoint. However, the farm has 2 languages (English and Dutch). When trying to connect the server, it will complain about: A. both languages not being installed (yes, really) and also all other languages are not installed....and B. Of course the SP1 for Languages of Foundations (it is an SharePoint Enterprise Server) are not present....

I get really annoyed, hope one of you guys have some pointer

Answer (score 0):

Clearing Configuration Wizard and refresh Config Wizard worked for me.